# How to insert many tags using foreign key?

Tags: laravel, tags, taglist

[submit function[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NjNmN.jpg)[error message while inserting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5EtY1.jpg)[function for inserting tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5EtY1.jpg)error while inserting into database many tags using foreign key .I am getting problem in array , it is unable to insert many tags

```
 public function uploadSubmit(UploadRequest $request)
{
    $product = new Product();
    $product->name = $request['name'];
    $product->save();



    //$product = Product::create($request->all());
    foreach ($request->photos as $photo) {
        $filename = $photo->store('photos');
        ProductsPhoto::create([
            'product_id' => $product->id,
            'filename' => $filename
        ]);

    }
    $tags = array();
    $tags = array($request['tagname[]']);
    foreach ($tags as $tag) {


        ProductTag::create([
            'tag_id' => $product->id,
            'tagname' => $tag,
        ]);
    }
    $message = 'Upload successful!';
    return redirect('/upload')->with('msg' , $message);
}
```

[Environment & details:[][2]][sql error 3]

Comment: Please share the actual error in your question (not in a comment).  Also, please share some of your code.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/as7jl.jpg

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEXOG.jpg

Comment: Nope, please do not put it in the comments (as I said before) -actually edit your question.  Also, images of code are not allowed.  You need to copy and paste the *actual code* (not an image) into your *question* (not the comments).

Comment: i have posted my code in question you can see

Comment: I think you should replace ` $tags = array($request['tagname[]']);` with ` $tags = $request['tagname']` - you don't need to wrap array index and use square brackets why pulling it from the request. Also, I would probably first prepare my records and then use `ProductTag::insert` to use just one query rather than one for each tag - a bit more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Ok - so after learning a bit more about your current setup I think you would benefit from re-structuring it to the following:

1. Model `Product` to have `tags()` relationship method:

```php
public function tags(): MorphToMany
{
    return $this->morphToMany(Tag::class, 'taggable');
}
```

2. Add intermediate table `taggable`:

```bash
php artisan make:migration create_taggables_table --create=taggables
```

```php
class CreateTaggablesTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('taggables', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->unsignedInteger('tag_id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('taggable_id');
            $table->string('taggable_type');
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('taggables');
    }
}
```

3. Update your controller to add new tags, then associate them with product:

```php
public function uploadSubmit(UploadRequest $request)
{
    $product = new Product;
    $product->name = $request->name;
    $product->save();


    $photos = collect($request->photos)->map(function($photo) use ($product) {
        return [
            'product_id' => $product->id,
            'filename' => $photo->store('photos')
        ];
    })->toArray();

    ProductsPhoto::insert($photos);


    $tagsInUse = Tag::whereIn('name', $request->tagname);

    if (count($request->tagname) > $tagsInUse->count()) {

        $newTags = collect($request->tagname)->diff($tagsInUse->pluck('name')->values())->map(function (string $tag) {
            return ['name' => $tag];
        });

        Tag::insert($newTags->toArray());

        $tagIds = Tag::whereIn('name', $request->tagname)->pluck('id')->values();

    } else {

        $tagIds = $tagsInUse->pluck('id')->values();

    }

    $product->tags()->attach($tagIds);


    return redirect('/upload')->with('msg' , 'Upload successful!');
}
```

And here's a test for this setup:

```php
public function test()
{
    factory(Tag::class)->create(['name' => 'one']);
    factory(Tag::class)->create(['name' => 'two']);
    factory(Tag::class)->create(['name' => 'three']);

    $this->assertEquals(
        ['one', 'two', 'three'],
        Tag::all()->pluck('name')->toArray()
    );


    $requestTags = new Collection(['one', 'three', 'four', 'five']);

    $inUse = Tag::whereIn('name', $requestTags)->pluck('name')->values();

    $newTags = collect($requestTags)->diff($inUse)->map(function(string $tag) {
        return ['name' => $tag];
    });

    Tag::insert($newTags->toArray());

    $this->assertEquals(
        ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five'],
        Tag::all()->pluck('name')->toArray()
    );


    $product = factory(Product::class)->create(['name' => 'Bike']);

    $this->assertEmpty($product->tags);


    $tagIds = Tag::whereIn('name', $requestTags)->pluck('id')->values();

    $product->tags()->attach($tagIds);

    $this->assertEquals(
        ['one', 'three', 'four', 'five'],
        $product->fresh('tags')->tags->pluck('name')->toArray()
    );
}
```

Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations

Comment: it doesnot work i am getting error some thing like this SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`ninja`.`product_tags`, CONSTRAINT `product_tags_tag_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`tag_id`) REFERENCES `tags` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE) (SQL: insert into `product_tags` (`tag_id`, `tagname`) values (37, a,v,b))

Comment: Do you have a separate `Tag` model with a table for it? You've used `$product->id` for `tag_id` so perhaps that's where the issue is - you should first fetch existing tags that are matching what you've sent with the request - or created them and then associate with the `tag_id` rather than using `$product->id` ? What I would do in this case would be to set up a relationship between `Product` and `Tag` and use that to associate them, but you seem to have a different approach to that.

Comment: i have 2 models Tag & ProductTag

Comment: So you're duplicating `tagname` both on the `ProductTag` and `Tag` model?

Comment: Is it just `Product` that has tags or do you have any other models that also use it?

Comment: I've updated my answer with use of the `Polymorphic Relations`.

Comment: Did you try it?